# Stock images for web design

Tags: html, image, css

I was told that practicing building numerous sites (even for yourself) is the best way to improve skillset. However I am unsure what to do about images as these are only personal sites I do not want to spend lots of money on stock images and there wasn't many good free stock photos available. Can any web designers/developers suggest what the best process is for creating sites with little resources?

Thanks

Comment: 1) text editor 2) web browser 3) get to work. That's pretty much **ALL** you need to build a "website". it won't be a very useful site, but it'll still be a site.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have built sites before. I just wanted to see what processes other web designers out there do when drafting sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that stock photos are a waste of money if you are building for personal projects, but there are plenty of free stock photo websites:

http://deathtothestockphoto.com/ is a good choice

Buy a template from websites like themeforest or wrapbootstrap (google them) or the free templates on bootstrap's website: http://startbootstrap.com/.

Start making things and eventually study the pattern in which these simple templates are made.

Great resource: http://www.webdesignrepo.com/

Comment: I have used this stock photos - it is the cheapest one i have found...[stockhook](http://stockhook.com)